# TestNG code will compile in Eclipse but not in Jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng

I am currently building a framework for testing webpages using Java, Selenium, and TestNG.  In my build.xml I am referencing testing version 6.8.8.  In Eclipse I have also updated to this version.  As part of my tests I am using the retryAnalyzer to re-run failed tests once.  I am then cleaning up the testNG report using TTestListener to remove failed tests (removing the failed test result) that passed on the re-run (All code is below).

My problem is this.  When compiling and running my code in Eclipse everything works just fine; however, when I commit and then attempt to run through Jenkins I encounter an exception stating that I have incompatible types between ITestNGMethod and ITestResult.  Prior to testNG 6.8.6 the removeResult() method only allowed for ITestNGMethods, but according to documentation it now includes the ability to remove a ITestResult (this is evidenced in the fact that it works when running through Eclipse [[http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.testng/testng/6.8.8/org/testng/internal/ResultMap.java#ResultMap.removeResult%28org.testng.ITestResult%29]](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.testng/testng/6.8.8/org/testng/internal/ResultMap.java#ResultMap.removeResult%28org.testng.ITestResult%29%5d)).  It's almost as if Jenkins is using a difference compiler or is somehow not looking at the correct version of testNG.

I am specifically looking for help in how to resolve this by having Jenkins compile my code the same way that my instance of Eclipse does.

Any direction would be great!

Thanks.

Rough code for removing wrongly failed tests.  Since I am only re-running a test once if and only if it failed on it's first fun, I can assume that if a test is in the Failed and Passed list then it passed on it's subsequent attempt and can therefore be removed from the failed set.

```
Set<ITestResult> failedSet = context.getFailedTests().getResults(testMethod);
Set<ITestResult> passedSet = context.getPassedTests().getResults(testMethod);       


    for(ITestResult passedTest : passedSet)
    {
        for(ITestResult failedTest : failedSet)
        {
             //parameter[0] is a unique testID
            if(failedTest.getParameters()[0].equals(passedTest.getParameters()[0]))
            {
                context.getFailedTests().removeResult(failedTest);      
            }                   
        }
    }
```

The above works wonderfully in Eclipse, but won't even compile in Jenkins.  I get an exceptions stating:

```
 error: incompatible types: ITestResult cannot be converted to ITestNGMethod
[javac]                     context.getFailedTests().removeResult(failedTest);
```

Here is what my build.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
          Any modifications will be overwritten.
          To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
          directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
          as the first entry and export the buildfile again. --><project basedir="." default="build" name="Automation">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.7"/>
<property name="source" value="1.7"/>
<path id="TestNG.libraryclasspath">
    <pathelement location="../../../../../../eclipse/plugins/org.testng.eclipse_6.8.6.20130517_2218/lib/testng.jar"/>
</path>
<path id="Automation.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <path refid="TestNG.libraryclasspath"/>
    <pathelement location="../../../../../../selenium/lib/jtds-1.3.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../../../../../selenium/lib/sqljdbc4-2.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../../../../../selenium/lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.42.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../../../../../selenium/lib/testng-6.8.8.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../../../../../selenium/lib/reportng-1.1.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../../../../../selenium/lib/velocity-dep-1.4.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../../../../../selenium/lib/guice-3.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../../../../../../selenium/lib/saxon-8.7.jar"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="bin">
        <fileset dir="src">
            <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
        </fileset>
    </copy>
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
</target>
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
<target name="build-subprojects"/>
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="Automation.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>
<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
    <antcall target="build"/>
</target>

<taskdef name="testng" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask" classpathref="Automation.classpath" />
    <taskdef resource="testngtasks">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="../../../../../selenium/lib/testng-6.8.8.jar"/>
            </classpath>
    </taskdef>

<!-- = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = =
      macrodef: runTestNG          
     = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = = -->
<macrodef name="runTestNG">
    <attribute name="xmlFile" default="testng.xml" />
    <sequential>
        <testng classpathref="Automation.classpath" 
                outputdir="test-output" 
                haltonfailure="no" 
                useDefaultListeners="true" 
                listeners="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter">
            <sysproperty key="org.uncommons.reportng.title" value="FOX Test Automation Report"/>
            <sysproperty key="org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output" value="false"/>
            <xmlfileset dir="." includes="@{xmlFile}"/>
        </testng>
        <echo> /* Testng Report generated */ </echo>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="runXSLT">
    <sequential>
        <delete dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt"/> 
        <mkdir dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt"/> 
        <xslt in="${basedir}/test-output/testng-results.xml" 
            style="${basedir}/testng-results.xsl" out="${basedir}/testng-xslt/index.html"> 
            <classpath location="../../../../../../selenium/lib/saxon-8.7.jar" />
            <param expression="${basedir}/testng-xslt/" name="testNgXslt.outputDir"/> 
            <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks"/> 
            <param expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter"/>
            <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals"/> 
            <classpath refid="Automation.classpath"/> 
        </xslt> 
        <echo> /* XSLT Report generated */ </echo>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<target name="firstFile">
    <echo message="Running Hoverbar/Client/Job/Lead tests" />
    <runTestNG xmlFile="testng.xml" />  
</target>
<target name="test" depends="firstFile">
    <runXSLT />
</target>

<target name="secondFile">
        <echo message="Running Hoverbar/Client/Job/Lead tests" />
        <runTestNG xmlFile="testng1.xml" /> 
    </target>
<target name="test1" depends="secondFile">
        <runXSLT />
</target>

<!--target name="test1">
    <echo message="running second test"/>
    <testng classpathref="Automation.classpath" outputdir="testng_output">
         <xmlfileset dir="." includes="testng1.xml"/>
    </testng>
</target -->

<target name="thirdFile">
    <echo message="Running Hoverbar/Client/Job/Lead tests" />
    <runTestNG xmlFile="testng2.xml" /> 
</target>
<target name="provider2" depends="thirdFile">
    <runXSLT />
</target>

<target name="testngAll">
    <echo message="Running all automated tests" />
    <runTestNG xmlFile="testngAll.xml" />
</target>
<target name="AllTests" depends="testngAll">
    <runXSLT />
</target>

<!-- Running Tests and TestNG report generation -->
<!--target name="run">
    <testng classpathref="Automation.classpath" 
            outputdir="test-output" 
            haltonfailure="no" 
            useDefaultListeners="true" 
            listeners="org.uncommons.reportng.HTMLReporter,org.uncommons.reportng.JUnitXMLReporter">
        <sysproperty key="org.uncommons.reportng.title" value="FOX Test Automation Report"/>
        <sysproperty key="org.uncommons.reportng.escape-output" value="false"/>
        <xmlfileset dir="." includes="testngAll.xml"/>
    </testng>
    <echo> /* Testng Report generated */ </echo>
</target>
<target name="xslt" depends="run"> 
    <delete dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt"/> 
    <mkdir dir="${basedir}/testng-xslt"/> 
    <xslt in="${basedir}/test-output/testng-results.xml" 
        style="${basedir}/testng-results.xsl" out="${basedir}/testng-xslt/index.html"> 
        <classpath location="../../../../../../selenium/lib/saxon-8.7.jar" />
        <param expression="${basedir}/testng-xslt/" name="testNgXslt.outputDir"/> 
        <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.sortTestCaseLinks"/> 
        <param expression="FAIL,SKIP,PASS,CONF,BY_CLASS" name="testNgXslt.testDetailsFilter"/>
        <param expression="true" name="testNgXslt.showRuntimeTotals"/> 
        <classpath refid="Automation.classpath"/> 
    </xslt> 
    <echo> /* XSLT Report generated */ </echo>
</target -->
```

A little more info:
Jenkins is running on a server (and has no connection to Ecliplse).

Here is the definition of the method I am trying to use: org.testng.IResultMap.removeResult(ITestResult r)

Comment: Your path has two testng jars - one with the plugin and one from your lib.  Can you try removing the plugin jar ref?

Comment: Thank you very much niharika_neo for the quick reply!  I'll give it a try and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I tried removing the plugin jar and I'm sorry to say it didn't fix it, though it was good to clean that up anyway.  Still hoping for some more ideas.